# PFC Application Report equation terms

Tags: power-factor-correction

I am working on a PFC for a final project.  The PFC is based on several sources and runs in CCM, currently have it working with a very noisy current waveform.  My original design was to use a 60kHz PWM frequency, but as I am using C functions as opposed to assembly, the platform (C2000 Launchpad) I am using is not fast enough and currently running at 25kHz for the PWM.

So I am looking to improve my algorithm and hopefully increase the PWM in the process.  Which brings me to the [Texas Instruments Application Report SPRA902A](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra902a/spra902a.pdf).

At the top of page 10 there are 3 equations, and I am able (95% sure) to identify all the parameters except for 1, which is \$U_s\$ which forms the term \$Epi\$.  The equations are below:

$$U_{CA}(n) = K0 \times E(n) + I(n-1)$$
$$I(n) = I(n-1) + K1 \times E(n) + K_{corr} \times Epi$$
$$Epi = U_s - U_{CA}(n)$$

I can see \$U_s\$ in the expression, but **how is it derived?**

Comment: The words that describe Us (below the 3 equations you list) - do these not help you understand at all?

Comment: Hi Andy, I can see Us is mentioned there but having trouble seeing how it is derived.  As my understanding is Uca is the output from the current controller as per Fig.2 on page 4.